# Need to transform an xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on an XSLT where I transforming an XML into an nice looking html markup.

I have below input XML :

```
<entry in_force_from="20011201" colname="2" morerows="0">
    <text in_force_from="20011201" newpara="N">A
        <autodeftext glossary-id="G430"> firm</autodeftext> must conduct its business with integrity.
    </text>
</entry>
```

And I want to transform this into :

```
<div>
    A<a href="hell.aspx?id=G430"> firm</a> must conduct its business with integrity.
</div>
```

Most of the transformation is quite straight forward except the creation of this a link node.

Comment: Can you show the XSLT you currently have? (Maybe at least the XSLT that currently transforms the `text` into ` div`) Thanks!

Comment: Tim, here is the one that I will use : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <div>
      <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: Can you edit your question to show this XSLT, as code is always hard to read in comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `xsl:value-of` to get the value of the `text` node, you should use `xsl:apply-templates` to allow you to add more templates to transform the descendant nodes

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/> 
  <xsl:template match="entry"> 
    <div> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="text"/> 
    </div> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="autodeftext">
    <a href="hell.aspx?id={@glossary-id}">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
    </a>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Strictly speaking, you could actually remove the template matching `text` here as XSLT's [built-in template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) will do the same thing in this case anyway.

Note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) in creating the `href` attribute, to simplify the code.

Comment: Brilliant Tim. Thanks for your help.